# How to find a limit of these sequence?

Tags: limits

$a_{n} = (1,0001 - \frac{1}{5^{n}})^{5n}$

I've tried to use squeeze theorem, but don't know how to find apropriate upper sequence:

$b_{n} \le a_{n} \le c_{n}$

$b_{n} = (1 - \frac{1}{5^n})^{5n} = ((1 - \frac{1}{5^n})^\frac{1}{5n})^{25n^2} = e^{25n^2} $

Comment: Your sequence is not bounded.

Comment: Could you explain how to proove it?

Comment: Try to find a positive sequence that diverges and less than $a_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $d_n = 1.00001^{5n}$ we have $d_n \leq a_n$ for large $n$. Since $d_n\to \infty$, so does $a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$ \left(1.0001 - \frac{1}{5^{n}}\right)^{5n}=e^{5n\log\left(1.0001 - \frac{1}{5^{n}}\right)} \to \infty$$

indeed

$$5n\log\left(1.0001 - \frac{1}{5^{n}}\right) \to \infty\cdot\log(1.0001)$$

Answer (score 1):

You may simply "plug in" $n=\infty$, which would give you $(1.0001-\frac{1}{\infty})^{\infty}=(1.0001-0)^{\infty}=\infty$, using that a number $>1$ raised to infinity is infinity (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Limits_of_powers)).

Alternatively, you can show that for every $m>0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $a_n > m$.